# h5py: HDF5 dataset name conflicts with group name

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, hdf5, h5py, python-3.11

Note: This is @hamo's original question.
The question was updated/clarified as an "answer" here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77574693/10462884.
The associated answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77575182/10462884

---

This code has had me working for hours without coming to a solution.
The program does not find the path in the file, so it creates a new dataset. However then it throws the following `TypeError()`:

```
TypeError: "Incompatible object (Dataset) already exists"
```

If I try to just update the value with via `dset = file[hdf5_path]`, it throws this error:

```
Unable to open object (message type not found)
```

This code generates the problem above:

```py
    hdf5_path = "path/to/my/dataset"
    with h5py.File(hdf5_path, "r+") as file:
        if hdf5_path in file:
            dset = file[hdf5_path]
            dset[...] = new_data_set
        else:
            file.create_dataset(hdf5_path, data=pixel_count)
```

---

The following code instead generates an error the second time in the loop, i.e. creating the group "my_path/to_another": "Unable to create group (message type not found)"

```py
    import h5py
    data_set = [1,2,3,4]
    fname = "temp.h5"
    h5_path = "my_path"
    with h5py.File(fname, "r+") as file:
        if h5_path in file:
            dset = file[h5_path] 
            dset[...] = data_set
        else:
            file.create_dataset(h5_path, data=data_set)

    h5_path = "my_path/to_another/dest"
    with h5py.File(fname, "r+") as file:
        current_path = ""
        for part in h5_path.split('/')[:-1]:
            current_path = f"{current_path}/{part}" if current_path else part
            if current_path not in file:
                file.create_group(current_path)
        if h5_path in file:
            dset = file[h5_path] 
            dset[...] = data_set
        else:
            file.create_dataset(h5_path, data=data_set)
```

Could it be that the files are corrupted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is a follow-up to @hamo's answer with "purported issue". As you discovered, you have to check if the `file[dset_tag]` is a dataset, but also have to check all names along the path are groups (except the last one used for the dataset). The logic gets a little trickier. I addressed it by creating a simple function to check that all path names are NOT datasets. Then you can use it in the original logic. I modified your example to create a file that mimics your problem. The file is 1st created with a dataset named `post/cams/thermal` then tries to create a dataset named `post/cams/thermal/pixels`.

Code below:

```
def group_path_ok(pset_path):
    pset_path = dset_tag.split('/')
    group_path = ''
    for name in pset_path[:-1]:
        group_path += '/' + name
        if group_path in file and isinstance(file[group_path], h5py.Dataset):
            print(f'group name: {group_path} in path is a dataset')
            return False
    return True
            
    
fname = "copyfile.h5"
pixel_count = [i for i in range(10)]
dset_tag = "post/cams/thermal"

with h5py.File(fname, "w") as file:
    file.create_dataset(dset_tag, data=pixel_count)

pixel_count = [i for i in range(17)]
dset_tag = "post/cams/thermal/pixels"   
with h5py.File(fname, "r+") as file:
    if group_path_ok(pset_path):
        if dset_tag in file:
            del file[dset_tag]
            print("Dataset deleted")
        file.create_dataset(dset_tag, data=pixel_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have errors in both methods, so most likely the file is not corrupted. I will explain, then provide working code.

In the 1st example, you use `hdf5_path` as both the H5 file name and the name of the dataset path. Also, the `create_dataset()` method references `dset_tag` as the dataset name. Are those a typos or cut-n-paste errors?

In the 2nd example, the 1st `with/as` block creates a DATASET named `my_path`. That triggers the error in the 2nd `with/as` block. You are trying to create a dataset with `h5_path = "my_path/to_another/dest"`. That means `my_path` must now be a **GROUP** (when it was just created as a **DATASET**). That's why you get an error. Also, you don't need to create the intermediate groups; the `create_dataset()` method will do that for you. I modified your indexing to h5py preferred format (from `[...]` to `[()]`, and removed lines with `dset = file[h5_path]` to reduce code).

Your code doesn't test modification of data in an existing dataset. I added a third segment to do that.  Note: this will only work if the new data matches the type and shape of the existing dataset. You will get an error if the shape changes, or you change from ints to strings. Worse, if the new data changes from ints to floats, you will get an undetected error as the floats will be saved as ints.

Modified code below:

```
import h5py  
data_set = [1,2,3,4]
fname = "temp.h5"
h5_path = "my_path/dest1"
with h5py.File(fname, "r+") as file:
    if h5_path in file:
        file[h5_path][...] = data_set
    else:
        file.create_dataset(h5_path, data=data_set)

h5_path = "my_path/dest2"
with h5py.File(fname, "r+") as file:
    if h5_path in file:
        file[h5_path][...] = data_set
    else:
        file.create_dataset(h5_path, data=data_set)

data_set = [11,12,13,14]
with h5py.File(fname, "r+") as file:
    if h5_path in file:
        file[h5_path][()] = data_set
    else:
        file.create_dataset(h5_path, data=data_set)
    print(file[h5_path][()])
```

Comment: How silly of me if this is the error. I'm writing this on a phone but I'll try when I get back on a computer

Comment: Ok, so now I had time to check it out a bit. 
Firstly: yes, the dset_tag instead of h5_path was an error when I tried to tidy up the code for stack overflow. I have fixed this error

Comment: Secondly, the dataset creation only iterates through h5_path.split('/')[:-1], so the data set will not name clash with the group name. I added this as part of the debugging process but I get that it is superfluous

Comment: To the point: your example works for the test file that is generated, but if I replace it by my file I still get the error I reported in the original post. Because you said the new data set has to be exactly the same as the previous, I have tried deleting it:

fname = "copyfile.h5"  # My data file
#fname = "temp.h5"
dset_tag = "post/cams/thermal/sensor_coverage"
data_set = [1, 10, 11]
with h5py.File(fname, "r+") as file:
    if dset_tag in file:
        del file[dset_tag]
    else:
        file.create_dataset(dset_tag, data=data_set)

Comment: The odd part is "dset_tag in file" returns False, but then I get type error "Incompatible object (Dataset) already exists"

Comment: Sorry posting code as a comment was a bad idea. I am currently not able to edit the post

Comment: I found the issue see my reply to the post. Thanks for putting me on the right track

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally found the purported issue:

```
import h5py

pixel_count = [i for i in range(17)]
fname = "copyfile.h5"
dset_tag = "post/cams/thermal/pixels"
with h5py.File(fname, "r+") as file:
    if dset_tag in file:
        del file[dset_tag]
        print("Dataset deleted")
    file.create_dataset(dset_tag, data=pixel_count)
```

Problem here is that thermal was a dataset in the original file, not a group! Thus "post/cams/thermal/pixels" is not in file, and hence is not deleted, however I cannot create the dataset either as it would be a child of a group.

The error message,

> "ValueError: Unable to create dataset (name already exists)"

did not make me realize what the problem was, until [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77571850/4559289) put me on the right track.

Comment: Hi hamo, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: Cannot check my own post as solution until after two days.

Comment: Also don't have enough score to give points to other posts